# How to write code for printing only 1 and 0 present in the list using streams API java?

Tags: java

```
public static void pickingNumbers(List<Integer> a) {

    List<Integer> diff = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        diff.add(Math.abs(a.get(i) - a.get(i-1)));
    }

    long ct = diff.stream().filter(i-> i==1).filter(i-> i==0).count();
}
```

Comment: You have to merge the two `filter` calls to `filter(i->i==1||i==0)`, otherwise you get an empty stream, as you first filter for all integers of value one and then filter for all integers of value zero. This would always result in zero elements

Comment: ohh yeaahhh...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
diff.stream().filter(i-> (i & 1) == i).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or if  you want to count them

```
long ct = diff.stream().filter(i-> (i & 1) == i).count();
```

In both of these cases the filter masks off the lower bit and checks to see if it is equal to the original number.